# Intellij-idea todo scope and git change list

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Our team loves using todos when code reviewing each other's work and in a perfect world, everyone would complete every todo after each code review. Unfortunately we work with a legacy system and there are hundreds of uncompleted todos littered throughout the project.

That said, I was hoping to use intellij's scope functionality to limit the search to just files that were changed in a specific git commit, i.e. when I open up version control and select a commit, I see a list of changed files to the right, I want to be able to search for todos only within that list of files.

Any advice on how to achieve this?